# Avoid computing an intercept in glmnet::cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am using `glmnet` (version 4.1-2) with `cv.glmnet` to fit a Lasso model. Based on the vignettes, you can use `intercept = FALSE` in `glmnet::glmnet`, so I thought I could do the same also with `cv.glmnet`, but if I use the same argument and I print the list of coefficients resulting from `cv.glmnet`, `(Intercept)` is still there and some of the values are different from zero. Any suggestion on how to do CV without fitting the intercept?

---

Forgot to mention that I am doing multi-task learning. That is, my `y` is a matrix of responses rather than a vector:

```
cv.mfit <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(dat.preprocessed$exposures), # nxp
                             y = as.matrix(dat.preprocessed$omics), # nxq
                             family = "mgaussian", alpha = 1, 
                             standardize = FALSE, standardize.response = FALSE, 
                             intercept = FALSE)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, see below

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, I am on `glmnet_4.1-1` and if I set `intercept=FALSE`, I get all 0s for intercepts:

```
library(glmnet)
x = as.matrix(mtcars[,1:9])
y = as.matrix(mtcars[,10:11])
fit = glmnet(x=x,y=y,alpha=1,intercept=FALSE,family="mgaussian")

table(fit$a0)

 0 
200

cvfit = cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,alpha=1,intercept=FALSE,family="mgaussian")
table(cvfit$glmnet.fit$a0)

  0 
200


cv.mfit = glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = x,y = y,
                             family = "mgaussian", alpha = 1, 
                             standardize = FALSE,
                             standardize.response = FALSE, 
                             intercept = FALSE)

table(cv.mfit$glmnet.fit$a0)
  0 
200
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Interesting. I forgot to mention that my `y` is a matrix and not a vector.

Comment: can you please provide the code, i.e what family or regression and if possible some example data? @wrong_path, as you can see, your question is incredibly vague. just to be clear, it's mgaussian you are using?